# Determine vulnerable programs affected by glibc's ghost bug?

Tags: shell, glibc, vulnerabilities

How do I determine the programs that are installed on my system which could be vulnerable to glibc's ghost bug? (Presuming the system has a vulnerable version of the libc6 library).

Posts like [How To Patch and Protect Linux Server Against the Glibc GHOST Vulnerability # CVE-2015-0235](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cve-2015-0235-patch-ghost-on-debian-ubuntu-fedora-centos-rhel-linux/) are helpful, but `lsof` may not be the best way to test for it.

Comment: Almost all programs use `libc`, although they don't necessarily use the vulnerable function `gethostbyname()`.

Comment: @Barmar - yes, agreed. But I'm only interested in what is installed and vulnerable.

Comment: So you want all the programs that use the vulnerable libc, or that use the broken function?

Comment: A program could be vulnerable indirectly. It might use some other library that in turn uses `gethostbyname`. What's the point of this exercise?

Comment: @Barmar - the point of the exercise is to evaluate the risk to a system. If no programs use the vulnerable functions, then there's no incumbent risk. If some programs use the vulnerable functions, then I need to know which ones so I can evaluate risk. If the risk is too great, then I might have to shut down forward facing services. If no forward facing services use the function, then I might be OK.

Comment: The vulnerable function is the one that translates hostnames to IP addresses, so most programs that deal with the network use it. But they're only really vulnerable if they get the hostnames from untrusted sources. This is not something that can be determined by scanning the system, you need to understand the nature of each application.

Comment: @Barmar - thanks. *"... you need to understand the nature of each application"* - And how do I get the list of applications so I can evaluate them?

Comment: Maybe you can use `nm` on every program that uses `libc`, and see if it references `gethostbyname`. But like I said, that won't find programs that use some other library that uses this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's more that one way to skin a cat. Below is how I skinned it.

```
#! /bin/sh

EXE_DIRECTORIES="/bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin"
SO_DIRECTORIES="/lib /lib64 /usr/local/lib"
FILES=
VULNERABLE=

echo "Generating file list..."
for d in $EXE_DIRECTORIES ; do

    TEMP=`find "$d" -type f -executable -exec file -i '{}' \; | grep 'x-executable; charset=binary' | cut -f 1 -d:`

    for t in "$TEMP" ; do   
        FILES="$FILES $t"
    done
done

for d in $SO_DIRECTORIES ; do

    TEMP=`find "$d" -type f -executable -exec file -i '{}' \; | grep 'x-executable; charset=binary' | cut -f 1 -d:`

    for t in "$TEMP" ; do   
        FILES="$FILES $t"
    done
done

echo "Testing executables..."
for f in $FILES ; do
    COUNT=`nm -D "$f" 2>/dev/null | grep gethostbyname | grep -c -w U`
    if [ "$COUNT" -ne 0 ]; then
      VULNERABLE="$VULNERABLE $f"
    fi
done

COUNT1=`echo "$FILES" | wc -l`
COUNT2=`echo "$VULNERABLE" | grep -o " " | wc -l`
if [ "$COUNT2" -ne 0 ]; then
  COUNT2=$(( $COUNT2 + 1 ))
fi

echo "Examined components: $COUNT1"
echo "Vulnerable components: $COUNT2"
echo "*****************************"
for v in $VULNERABLE ; do
    echo "$v"
done
```

On a typical Ubuntu 14 development system, here's what I am getting:

```
$ ./glibc-check.sh
Generating file list...
Testing executables...
Examined components: 961
Vulnerable components: 32
*****************************
/bin/ss
/bin/hostname
/bin/tar
/bin/cpio
/bin/netstat
/bin/ping
/bin/mt-gnu
/sbin/agetty
/sbin/route
/sbin/rarp
/sbin/ifconfig
/sbin/getty
/usr/bin/logger
/usr/bin/git-upload-pack
/usr/bin/aseqnet
/usr/bin/git
/usr/bin/telnet.netkit
/usr/bin/getent
/usr/bin/mtr
/usr/bin/mtools
/usr/bin/gethostip
/usr/bin/gdb
/usr/bin/tracepath
/usr/bin/python3.4m
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/arping
/usr/bin/python3.4
/usr/bin/traceroute6.iputils
/usr/bin/openssl
/usr/bin/git-shell
/usr/bin/rsync
```

But its only a subset of the 19000+ packages that depend on libc6 (its only the installed packages; and its only components in well known locations):

```
$ apt-cache rdepends libc6 | wc -l
19125
```